# Variadic templates and C arrays

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to compile the following piece of code:

```
template <typename T, int N> void foo( const T (&array)[N]) {}

template <typename T> static int args_fwd_(T const &t) { foo(t); return 0; }

template<class ...Us> void mycall(Us... args) {
    int xs[] = { args_fwd_(args)... };
}

int main(void) {
    int b[4];
    mycall(b);
}
```

The `mycall` function uses variadic templates and then forwards to the `args_fwd_` function to call the function `foo` on each argument.

This works fine for most argument types (assuming I have appropriately defined `foo` functions). But when I try to pass a C-style array (`int b[4]`) it gets turned into a pointer and then it can't find the templated `foo` function that requires an array (not pointer). The error from gcc 4.9.3 is as follows:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘foo(int* const&)’
note: candidate is:
note: template<class T, int N> void foo(const T (&)[N])
   template <typename T, int N> void foo( const T (&array)[N]) {}
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   mismatched types ‘const T [N]’ and ‘int* const’
```

Note the part about looking for a pointer. This is the same in clang as well so apparently this is standard compliant. Is there a way to preserve that this is a C array without it getting converted to a pointer?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with templating on array types like this is: there is a separate instantiation for each size of array that you use it on. Depending on how many differently sized arrays you have in your program, that could mean a significant amount of bloat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Use perfect forwarding:

```
#include <utility>

template<class ...Us> void mycall(Us&&... args) {
    int xs[] = { args_fwd_(std::forward<Us>(args))... };
}
```